# Downsampling pandas Dataframe to arbitrary length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series of daily values over a year:

```
DATE          VAL
2017-01-01   -0.298653
2017-01-02   -0.224910
2017-01-03   -0.216723
....
2017-12-29    0.061681
2017-12-30    0.078109
2017-12-31    0.106636
Freq: D, Length: 365, dtype: float64
```

I need to transform this series of **365** values in the `VAL` column into a series of **272** values, by averaging the original values.

I imagine that I need to "resample" this sequence of values at 365/272 the frequency.

I have considered `resample` and `asfreq` but these only seem to allow me to change the frequency in whole time units.

Unfortunately my grasp of mathematics, as well as my python skills, are lacking here. Would very much appreciate some pointers on how to think about this!

**EDIT:**

Before adopting Graipher's superior solution below i settled for this approximation:

```
step = 365/float(272)
a = np.zeros(shape=(272,))
for i in range(0, 272):
    a[i] = df[int(round(i * step))]
```

Comment: There is a distinction between "What result should I aim for?", "How should I write code to get the result I'm aiming for?", and "I wrote some code to get the result I'm aiming for, but it's not working, can anyone tell me why?" The last one is what SO is primarily focused on, the second is more Code Review, and the first is neither. Your question is largely in this first category. Cross Validated or Mathematics might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Acccumulation The second is actually not Code Review at all. It would be 4. "I wrote some code that does this and works, how can I make it better?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use the `pd.DataFrame.resample` function for this, it allows also fractional time units. You just have to make sure to first set the date as index and make sure that it is a datetime object:

```
def resample(df, target_freq, unit_str):
    resample_str = "{:.4g}{}".format(len(df)/target_freq, unit_str)
    return df.resample(resample_str).mean()

df = ...    # your definition here
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df = df.set_index('DATE')

df_resampled = resample(df, 272., "D")
print(len(df_resampled))
# 272
```

However, the fractional value can not be of arbitrary length. `df.resample("{:.4g}D".format(365./272))` works, but `df.resample("{}D".format(365./272))` does not. Somewhere between four and five digits seems to be the limit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did try a fractional day unit, but must have messed up somewhere, and assumed the it was not possible. This works perfectly.

Comment: @RasmusSvensson It seems to stop working at some length after the decimal point. Therefore the `"{:.4g}"` part to keep it accurate to 4 significant digits (which should be enough in most cases). `"{}{}".format(len(df)/target_freq, unit_str)` does not work with `365./272`.